# Snakemake --use-singularity waits at downloading image

Tags: docker, snakemake, singularity-container

I am trying to run a snakemake command in a docker container. I use the command `snakemake -j all --use-singularity --verbose`, but it gets hung up on `Pulling singularity image [image]`. I have an example snakefile below

```
rule run_guppy:
    input:
        "../../data/fast5"
    output:
        "output"
    container: "docker://joshloecker/guppy:latest"
    params:
        config = "dna_r9.4.1_450bps_fast.cfg",
        callers = 1,
        threads_per_caller = 12
    shell:
        """
        echo Basecalling           

        guppy_basecaller \
        --config {params.config} \
        --input_path {input} \
        --save_path {output} \
        --num_callers {params.callers} \
        --cpu_threads_per_caller {params.threads_per_caller} \
        --recursive
    """
```

But as I said, this doesn't get further than `Pulling singularity image. . .`.
Do I need to reconfigure my docker image as a singularity image?

Comment: You may want to check if singularity can create the image properly using `singularity pull docker://joshloecker/guppy:latest`. This command resulted in successful image creation for me though.

Comment: I never use singularity so I can't really give input here, but maybe updating to the newest snakemake version helps? (if you werent already using that)

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy Running your command shows singularity stuck at `Getting image source sisignatures`

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande I am on snakemake version 5.31.1

Comment: So the error has to do purely with singularity and not snakemake. Since I could pull the image successfully using singularity v3.5.2, the error may have to do with your singularity version. Which version do you use?

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy I am running on a cluster, with version 3.6.4-1.el7

Comment: It might be worthwhile to try some other version of singularity, if you have access.

Comment: When you say "doesn't get further" do you mean errors out? Does it crash? Just hang for a while? I am also unable to find a `joshloecker/guppy:latest` when I attempt to reproduce the error, is this a private image on docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my filesystem was just extremely slow in downloading the image from docker. I did not see any progress from the command line, and assumed something was wrong.